# How to split training and test data

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to ML and python.
Not sure if I am doing it correct?
my code:

```
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
(x_train,y_train),(x_test,y_test)=keras.datasets.fashion_mnist.load_data()
# x train data from 0 to 2000 and x validation data from 2000 to end
x_train_subset,x_valid = fashion_mnist[:2000],fashion_mnist[2000:]
# ytrain data from 0 to 2000 and yvalidation data from 2000 to end
y_train_subset,y_valid= fashion_mnist[:2000],fashion_mnist[2000:]
# x test from 0 to 500
x_test = fashion_mnist[:500]
# ytest from 0 to 5000
y_test= fashion_mnist[500:]
```

Comment: Search at google first. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How training and test data is split - Keras on Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51006505/how-training-and-test-data-is-split-keras-on-tensorflow)

Comment: Found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48566821/is-there-a-keras-method-to-split-data), this might help you. Thanks!